# PhpUnit ERROR: Unknown option, coverage-html, specified

Tags: phpunit, code-coverage

I'm trying to run phpunit with coverage. But when I run this command

```
vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit   --coverage-html coverage test/CommonFlags.php
```

I receive this error

```
ERROR: Unknown option, coverage-html, specified
```

Without any options, the command works.
I'm running on Ubuntu with PHPUnit 4.6.4.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: PHPUnit 4.6.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Comment: `php -v`

output

`PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.7 (cli) (built: Mar 16 2015 20:47:39) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
`

Answer (score 0):

The "ERROR: Unknown option, coverage-html, specified" error message is not generated by PHPUnit. If you would call "phpunit --unknown-option" you would get "unrecognized option --unknown-option" and not "ERROR: Unknown option, unknown-option, specified".

Are you sure that `vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit` is in fact PHPUnit? If you install PHPUnit via Composer then PHPUnit's binary is at `vendor/bin/phpunit` and not `vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit`.

Comment: I've tried:
`vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-html coverage test/CommonFlagsTest.php
PHPUnit 4.6.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

I....ERROR: Unknown option, coverage-html, specified 
`